# Bash shell script file exists

Tags: linux

Hi my bash script says the that the first parameter passed into it doesn't exist as a file but it does.  Please what have I done wrong?

to run the script and pass in two arguments from linux:
`./concantenatefile.sh file1.txt file2.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash

file1="$1"

if [ -e file1 ]
then    
    echo "The file $file1 exists"
else    
    echo "The file $file1 doesn't exist"
fi
```

It says
`The file file1.txt doesn't exist`
However there is a file called file1.txt in the present working directory.

Comment: `if [ -e $file1 ]` - you missed the `$` sigil before the variable name.

Answer (score -1):

you are not currently derefencing the file1 variable 
In the line

```
if [ -e file1 ]
```

You need to add a $ to derefence the variable and access its content as so

```
if [ -e $file1 ]
```